# What are some Bitcoin / blockchain projects that are actually doing something?

Tags: blockchain

There are hundreds of blockchain startups out there across a range of industries -- from finance to media to property management. They have identified significant problems and ways that blockchain can solve them. On paper, it all sounds awesome.

But how many blockchain companies or projects have created working solutions? It seems to me that most companies just have ideas, and are still working on their code. In the best cases their platforms are still in the alpha stages and they might have a few users or partners (who are usually willing to pay or be paid in cryptocurrency, which makes them different from the public at large), but have not yet really made a big impact.

Can anyone think of examples of blockchain companies or projects that have a real, fully functioning platform that is actually being used by a critical mass of users who are not themselves all blockchain fanatics?

I'm not asking to be critical. I am really excited by the potential of blockchain. But when people who are not blockchain geeks ask me for examples of how blockchain is actually being used in a meaningful way today, rather than how it could theoretically be used in the future to solve all sorts of problems, I don't have good answers.

I know this question is about blockchain as a whole, not just Bitcoin, but there is no blockchain Stack Exchange, so here we are.

Comment: huuh, we can't give you the arguments, that you need to convince "nay sayers" - if there is a crypto ccy market approaching 1 trillion, then there must be something fundamental behind, besides some geeks getting wet dreams on crypto currency. And whatever argument you make, it might turn into "Bitcoin is only a bubble". Really think twice, if you have any value to fight arguments with people, who don't see a value in the world, that you yourself find fascinating...

Answer (score 0):

My favorites,

Ether Delta(https://etherdelta.com),  Decentralized exchages controlled by zero entities.

Augur(http://augur.net) Decentralized prediction market/betting company.

So many more, at https://www.stateofthedapps.com

Answer (score 0):

When observing the market, I think there are several areas: there is for sure transfer of value over the internet (this is all the bitcoin and co stuff). And for sure all the ICOs using Ethereum as platform. Then there is a gaining market for smart contracts (also Ethereum, but others as well), which try to eliminate the middlemen, so that banks/assurances and lawyers (all very expensive parts in transactions) can be eliminated. Another area is some kind of proof, e.g with factum. There you can document, that at a certain time you published s.th, and everyone can verify it. These are some "public" examples.

Then there is the large area of private blockchains, where companies try to improve their workflows. The logistics industry is playing heavily with it (e.g. a container sends a message to the blockchain, that he arrived, and payments can be initiated), the financial industry is looking for better settlement processes, and the charging of electric cars was last recently a hot topic.

I personally like the idea of smart grids, where you produce power with e.g. solar panels, and sell it via crypto currency to the grid/consumer. 
And then there are for sure 100s of crypto currencies, which are used as a testing platform for new technologies.

Welcome to the exciting world of crypto currencies!

and next to my comment above, I wanted to add this picture, I cut&pasted from somewhere...

[image]